# What is acceptable to ask moderators to do?

Tags: support, voting, moderators

For example, I posted an answer that was downvoted without comment, I think because of an error in my example code. I fixed the error, but the downvote remains. Is it acceptable to ask a moderator to remove an undeserved downvote, or anything else? If not, how should such issues be handled?

Answer (score 2):

Moderators cannot remove votes on posts, and don't know who voted for a post. Moderators can:

- Delete posts
- Convert an answer in a comment
- Convert a post in Community Wiki
- Convert a Community Wiki in a normal post (which will never become a Community Wiki anymore)

If there were more than one vote, they could be caught from the script against voting irregularities, and removed, but a single down-vote is not considered vote fraud.

If the down-vote would have been given because the wrong code, it should be removed once the code has been fixed. Down-votes are not a punishment for the user who posted, but they are given for bad posts, or the wrong information given in the post.
As the [privilege page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-down) for voting down says:

> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

Comment: Is there any way to enforce rules such as the downvote guideline?

Comment: @beth There isn't (have a look at the questions on this [search for "downvote"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=downvotes) on meta SO), there's plenty of general and historical debate on the subject but as kiamlaluno says, unless there is suspected vote fraud nothing will be done (and in many people's opinion nothing _should_ be done). Either way don't take it personally, it may just be that the downvoter hasn't re-visited the question. They won't be notified of the edit so unless/until they come back of their own accord it's likely to remain as it is